# Default Media Receiver + Widevine DRM - how to pass a license URL

Tags: ios, chromecast

I would like to use Widevine DRM with Default Media Receiver. The problem which I have right now is to find a way to pass the license URL from sender to the receiver.

What I find in google cast help section:
"DRM content will play on a Styled Media Receiver or the Default Media Receiver, if you provide the DRM license/key information in the application's manifest file. " ([source](https://support.google.com/widevine/answer/6072130?hl=en))

But I can't find any piece of code example how to pass this licence to receiver.

Thank you for your answers!﻿

Comment: It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#drm) that "To fully support content protected with Digital Rights Management (DRM), you need to implement a Custom Receiver. With a Custom Receiver, you can set up authentication and tailor your application according to your DRM requirements."

Comment: I also found that the DRM content will play on a [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) or the [Default Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default), if you provide the DRM license/key information in the application's manifest file. But take note that there is no way to implement authentication for the content using either of these receivers. You can't override the license URL, pass custom parameters, or authenticate users with cookies or tokens.